# Collinearity and relationship between the parameter estimates

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Given a dataset with a dependent variable (Y), and three independent variables/features {X1,X2,X3}, where collinearity exists, and if we fit it using linear regression, is there any relationship between the parameter estimates?

Comment: Are you interested in a particular relationship?  If so, what kind?  It is a well known result that correlated predictors result in covariance in the sampling distirbution of the coefficients.

Comment: Do you mean the parameter estimates (or coefficients) are correlated？Can you point me to some source to look at it @DemetriPananos

Comment: Hey William, are you comfortable looking at a variance-covariance matrix? This is the clearest way to see correlation between parameter estimates, in my opinion.

Comment: Where *collinearity* exists, yes: there will exist linear relations among parameter estimates.  I would suppose, though, that you might be trying to ask about *multicollinearity,* which is a different phenomenon.  As far as correlation of parameter estimates goes, please search our site: you can find formulas for their variance-covariance matrix and many worked examples of its calculation and application.